# Does full backup work with simple recovery mode?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, logging, backup

I have a database that is getting to be huge.  The mdf file is about 150 GB and I just saw that the log file is nearing 1.5 TB!  I do not care about the log file at all.  So based on this, I plan on switching the recovery mode to simple.

However, I am concerned that I won't be able to do a full restore in the future if I have a simple recovery mode set.  Is this true?

Here is the code I use to backup my database nightly.  Would I be able to do a full restore in the future if my hard drive crashes or something gets corrupted?

```
BACKUP DATABASE MyDatabase
TO DISK = 'F:\SQL Server Backup\MyDatabase.bak'
WITH INIT
```

Comment: Works just fine - you can always restore to a last full (or differential) backup file that you have. You cannot however go back to a "point-in-time" backup like if you had transaction log backups. I do all my dev, test and staging work with simple recovery model

Comment: BWAAA-HAAA!!! I think it's funny as hell that a couple of people who closed this thread because it wasn't appropriate according to the FAQ still managed to get THEIR answers/comments in. ;-)  If you're going to be a cop about it all, set the example you expect others to follow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the **Simple Recovery Model** you will be able to take *Full* and *Differential* backups.  If you have a full backup, you will be able to restore the database in full at the time of the full backup.

A full backup in the simple recovery model has no less data than a full backup in the full recovery model.

If you do this:

```
backup database MySimpleRecoveryDatabase
to disk = 'F:\SQL Server Backup\MyDatabase.bak'
go
```

And then at a later date perform a `RESTORE`:

```
restore database MySimpleRecoveryDatabase
from disk = 'F:\SQL Server Backup\MyDatabase.bak'
go
```

Provided that `.bak` file was untouched between the backup and restore, you will have a full database restore that is equivalent to when you did the backup.  (Note, that `RESTORE DATABASE` command may not be all-inclusive depending on NTFS structure, existing files, etc.)

Comment: For what it's worth, if your transaction log is that big in Full Recovery, it sounds like you're not doing transaction log backups.  A well-designed t-log backup schedule can drastically minimize that size.  But if point-in-time recovery isn't required, there's no problem with Simple.

Comment: I switched to simple recovery mode, but the log hasn't shrunk yet.  Do I have to do something else to get it down to a reasonable size?  I do not care about any of the data in the log file.

Comment: Setting the recovery model to simple does not shrink the log, it only changes the way the space in the log file is used / re-used. If you want to shrink the log file, *one time*, look at [`DBCC SHRINKFILE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189493%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

No, that is not true. But in simple recovery mode, you won't be able to take log backups, so you will only be able to restore to the last full backup (or last full + diff).